# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: d3.js

When running the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%e-%m-%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("http://localhost/webserver/data/downloads.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined d3.v3.js:7296
```

That line has the following description:

```
 function d3_time_parse(date, template, string, j) {
    var c, p, i = 0, n = template.length, m = string.length;
```

My source data looks like the following:

Date;Value
23-4-2012;12
24-4-2012;10
25-4-2012;13
26-4-2012;24
27-4-2012;45

Answer (score 2):

your csv should have comma `,` as a separator and attributes are case sensitive. Try this:

```
date,value
23-4-2012,12
24-4-2012,10
25-4-2012,13
26-4-2012,24
27-4-2012,45
```

Comment: I changed the separator, but what do you mean with the attributes are case sensitive?

Comment: You have `d.date` and `d.value` in code but `Date` and `Value` in csv